# Cannot resolve class androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout or com.google.android.material.navigation.navigationview

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, gradle, dependencies

I have an app that works properly. Anyway, I have a "strange" behaviour of Android studio, in fact for the xml files it is not able to solve some classes, i.e. drawerLayout, constraintLayout, CircleImage etc. (see the image below)

[image: Android Studio Screenshot]

Before opening android studio I have a warning about adding project dependencies:

Problem: Inconsistencies in the existing project dependencies found.
Version incompatibility between:

- androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.5.1@aar and:
- androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.0@aar

With the dependency:

- androidx.annotation:*1.1.0
- androidx.annotation:*.2.0.0

What I tried:

- invalidating caches and restarting app
- update my gradle file, as shown below:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'
}
apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs"

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
        }
    }
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.frangela"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }

}

dependencies {

    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.5.1'
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.5.1"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.5.1"
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-common-ktx:20.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:20.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-buildtools:2.9.1'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.3.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions'
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1"
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:8.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.2.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.8'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4"
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout-compose:1.0.1"
}
```

My gradle Module:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    }
    dependencies {
        def nav_version = "2.5.1"
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version"
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I think that there could be problems with the dependencies, but for example I cannot find any of that regarding annotation in my gradle file.
Thank you in advance for anyone that could help me.

Answer (score 0):

You're applying `androidx.navigation.safeargs` twice and `srcDirs += 'build/generated/source/navigation-args'` also is useless. With high probability, this project is lacking a proper repositories configuration, while the question complete ignores this part. In case there should be any `jcenter()` repository, replace that with `mavenCentral()` or `google()`.

Comment: Thank you, I have edited my question (since I have noticed other problems when launching it)

Answer (score 0):

After hours of works, I solved in a pretty easy way:

- Copy all the project in another location on my PC
- Reopen the project

After opening it from Android Studio, everything works fine